# How do I add an image to my C++ Xcode Project?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode11

I'm trying to make Asteroids using the olcPixelGameEngine. I have a simple triangle sprite for the ship. I want to know how I would "include" this sprite while building. The only way I have found to do this is to place it right next to the binary in the build folder, which I don't want to do because I have read is bad practice.

Can somebody help, please? I am using Xcode 11.4.1

Comment: A [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093704/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-c-project-in-xcode) I found. Worked like charm.