# How do I get to see the contents of a NSData array in JXA?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, std, javascript-automation

I need to do some manipulation on a file byte array and as far as I have read, I cannot do this unless I use ObjectiveC bridging. This is what I have done for now:

```
var filepath = file.toString();
ObjC.import('stdlib');
ObjC.import('Foundation');

var theFileData = $.NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(filepath);
var fileSize = theFileData.length;
```

If I try using `$.malloc(filesize)` it will say the function is undefined... how am I supposed to check the contents of `theFileData` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone into this in-depth in [the answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57243326/9051006) to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235855/how-do-i-read-a-file-as-a-byte-array-in-applescript), so please refer to that for more details.

But here you go:

```js
function readBytes(filepath) {
    const bytes    = $.NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(
                        $.NSString.stringWithString(filepath)
                         .stringByStandardizingPath);
    const bytesPtr = bytes.bytes;
    var   bytesArr = [];
    const numBytes = Number(bytes.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
        bytesArr.push(bytesPtr[i]);
    }

    return bytesArr;    
}
```