# Could not find a *.json file inside an Xcode 12 project

Tags: swift5, xcode12

I'm trying both Swift (5.3) and Xcode (12) for the first time. The task is to parse a **.json* file, that already exists nearby.

Honestly, adding the file in Xcode project is more tricky than actually parsing it: wherever I put it, it is always not found. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10316284/4554883) didn't help, because [there's no Target Membership section in File Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UD83.png) (I guess, it was renamed or moved somewhere else in Xcode 12; maybe I'm wrong; anyway, couldn't find it as well).

I've also noticed that there's a difference in behavior of Target Membership section, when creating a new **Project** versus new **Swift Package**. If it is a Project, then Target Membership shows up. Since I've created a package, this section is not available for me.

Could someone help me understand what's going on here?

---

- The structure of the project (called "TryParseJSON", it is organised as a Swift Package) is as follows:

  ```yaml
  TryParseJSON/
    Package.swift
    Sources/
      TryParseJSON/
        main.swift # defines `findPath(to:)` and calls `findPath(to: "persons.json")`
        Person.swift
        persons.json # this file is not found
  ```
- The contents of `Package.swift` file are as follows:

  ```swift
  // swift-tools-version:5.3

  import PackageDescription

  let package = Package(
      name: "TryParseJSON",
      products: [
          .executable(name: "TryParseJSON", targets: ["TryParseJSON"]),
      ],
      targets: [
          .target(
              name: "TryParseJSON",
              dependencies: [],
              resources: [
                  .copy("persons.json"),
              ]
          ),
      ]
  )
  ```
- The path in `.copy("persons.json")` is relative to *main.swift*; if I put a path relative to *Package.swift* (`.copy("Sources/TryParseJSON/persons.json")`), Xcode doesn't find the JSON (the `"found 1 file(s) which are unhandled"` warning is shown), and the package still doesn't work; with `.copy("persons.json")` there's no warning.
- The *persons.json* file was added with <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>New</kbd> > <kbd>File</kbd> > "Empty" (category "Other") > rename to "persons.json".
- The `findPath` function:

  ```swift
  func findPath(to file: String) -> URL {
      guard
          let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil)
      else {
          fatalError("File \(file) was not found") // this is called
      }

      return path
  }
  ```
- This function is both defined and called inside *main.swift*:

  ```swift
  let path = findPath(to: "persons.json")
  ```

I don't know how this works, I don't know what exactly I'm supposed to do to "add a new member in the target", I don't know what targets and products are, and I'm frustrated that adding files in Xcode requires *that* much of an effort.

Comment: Can you include your `Package.swift` in the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Swift 5.3, packages have the ability to add and process non code resources. However, the `Package.swift` has to explicitly define them. Do this by adding the resources to the target:

```
targets: [
  .target(
    name: "TryParseJSON",
    resources: [
      .copy("persons.json")
    ]
  )
]
```

That will copy it into the Bundle, hopefully in the right place. If not, there may be extra config required.

Note that the path is relative to the directory containing the sources for the target. Apple recommends creating a subdirectory inside your source directory called `Resources`. If you do that you need

```
      .copy("Resources/persons.json")
```

Also, make sure `Package.swift` defines Swift tools 5.3 at the top like this:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
```

It also matters how you try to extract the URL of the file when you need to access it. According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package), you must always use `Bundle.module.url(forResource:,withExtension:)` to get the URL of the resource. So, in the above case use

```
guard let resourceUrl = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "persons",withExtension: "json")
else { /* fail */ }
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that, with no luck, unfortunately. I've updated the answer with details.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky I've done it for myself now, so I understand things better. Your main issueue now is, I think, the function you use to obtain the URL. It should be `Bundle.module.url(...)` not `Bundle.main.url(...)`. I've updated my answer.